# Is it possible for a linear transformation to be injective but not invertible?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

If so, could someone give me an example?

Answer (score 2):

$V = \mathbb{R}$ and $W = \{0\}$. Take any linear map $f : W \to V$. :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  For example, take the transformation $T:\Bbb R \to \Bbb R^2$ given by
$$
T(x) = (x,0)
$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $V$ be the vector space of all real sequences and let $T:V \to V$ be defined by

$T(x_1,x_2,x_3,....)=(0,x_1,x_2,x_3,...)$.

Then $T$ is injective but not surjective.