# For a linear transformation matrix to be invertible, does it need to only be either injective/surjective, or does it need to be bijective?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

In the book "No BS Linear Algebra," the author states that "for linear transformations to be invertible, it only needs to be either injective or subjective," mentioning the invertible matrix theorem where a matrix is invertible iff the matrix's null space is only the 0 vector.

However, a Google search on the Mathematics StackExchange gives [a different answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/894244/show-that-a-linear-matrix-transformation-is-bijective-iff-a-is-invertible), stating a linear transformation matrix is invertible iff it is bijective, and I'm a bit confused as to which is true.

Comment: If the vector spaces have the same dimension (and are finite) then invertibility is equivalent to surjectivity or injectivity. This is basically by rank-nullity but the intuition is the same as it is for finite sets

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is due to the rank-nullity theorem, which states that
$$
\dim(Range(T))+\dim(Kernel(T))=n
$$
for a transformation $T:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$.

If your transformation is surjective, $\dim(Range(T))=n$ and, therefore, $\dim(Kernel(T))=0$ (it is injective). By the same relation, injective implies surjective. The conclusion is: for linear transformations of a finite-dimensional space, injective, surjective and bijective are synonyms.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it cleared everything up for me. 
I'm guessing the conclusion doesn't necessarily hold true for non-finite-dimensional spaces (e.g. Hilbert space, etc.)?

Comment: Correct, in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2447563) by Fred, there is an example where $V$ is an infinite-dimensional vector space and $T:V\to V$ is a linear map that is injective but not invertible.

Answer (score 0):

For a linear application between two vector spaces of the **same finite dimension**, we have equivalence between surjectivity, injectivity and bijectivity.  You can translate this in terms of a (square) matrix since a matrix corresponds to an endomorphism and the invertibility of a matrix corresponds to the bijectivity of the associated endomorphism.

However it's false if for example you have a linear application between $\mathbb{R^3}$ and $\mathbb{R^4}$ which have a different dimension, or if you have infinite dimension vector space.